# Limit of multivariable functions

Tags: calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus

limit of $\sqrt{x^2 + y^2} \sin(1/y)$ as $(x,y) \rightarrow (0,0)$

limit of $2xy/(x^2 - y + 5xy)$ as $(x,y) \rightarrow(0,0)$

Having trouble finding the answers for the questions above. According to book in one of them limit shouldn't exist and in the another one limit should exist but i don't have the answer unfortunately. Appreciate any help.

Comment: For the first it might be easier to consider $x\sin(1/x)$ and then try to use the same logic.

Answer (score 0):

(1) $|\sin(1/y)|\le 1$
(2) Let $d$ the denominator when you divide top and bottom by $xy.$
If $x=y,$ $|d|$ goes to infinity.
If $x^2=y,$ $d$ goes to $5.$